# Session sweeping lottery

Tags: php, laravel, session

Can someone explain what a session sweeping lottery is? I've attached the default session config file for the Laravel framework.

Questions: 1. It says that some session drivers must *manually* sweep their
    storage location. Could someone describe this process and why it is
    necessary? What session drivers require this action?
    2. Why is a lottery necessary? If say some form of storage (database)
    is full, why does it have to be random? Why can't the framework
    sweep the old sessions when it detects that the driver is full?

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Sweeping Lottery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
| rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
| happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
|
*/

'lottery' => array(2, 100),
```

Comment: I think you got some decent answers.  For every request there is a "chance" that PHP will run code that determines if session files should be garbage collected, based on php.ini settings that configure the lifetime of session files.  So that is the "lottery" aspect of it.  An important thing to remember is that if you don't have sufficient traffic, it's possible that session files can be stored for longer than you might want them to, because there's not a high enough chance the session GC runs.

Comment: You can also store sessions in many different ways, with custom sessions handlers, with databases and caches (memcache, redis) which in many cases already have time to live (TTL) features in them, that might automatically delete entries.  So in some cases, it's best to effectively disable PHP's garbage collection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, a session is a piece of data that is stored on the server for a certain amount of time.

Imagine using a folder with files to store the sessions. There has to be a moment where the old sessions should be cleared. Because there is no way to automaticly check the files every x hours the session files are checked on certain requests. 
This setting is the chance this check will happen. In this case 2 out of 100 for every request.

I think the only session driver that currently needs this is the database driver.

If you sweep the storage when it is full, there is a chance that new sessions won't be able to start untill the storage has been sweeped.
If you would sweep the storage on every request, all of your requests would become very slow.

Comment: Is this 2 out of 100 requests in one session, or is it 2 out of 100 requests from multiple sessions? If it is the latter, it would appear that the 2 of 100 is far too frequent for any site with decent traffic, is that correct?

Comment: I understand the necessity to sweep for a database driver since I would image there are storage limits to different data types. Can you forsee any problems if I decreased the sweeping frequency to extremely low for a file session driver? e.g. (2 of 1000000)

Comment: The sweep won't happen in 2 out of 100 requests. The change of a sweep happening is 2 out of 100 for every requests.

Comment: As long as you have enough visitors to let the sweep happen once a day, I don't see any problem.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. And one more follow up - what could happen if sweeping just didn't occur for an extended period of time? (For a file session driver)

Comment: Your storrage will start filling up. :)

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with the answer from Jerodev.

For anyone looking for this right now, as of Laravel 8, here are the methods from:

\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php:

```
/**
 * Remove the garbage from the session if necessary.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Session\Session  $session
 * @return void
 */
protected function collectGarbage(Session $session)
{
    $config = $this->manager->getSessionConfig();

    // Here we will see if this request hits the garbage collection lottery by hitting
    // the odds needed to perform garbage collection on any given request. If we do
    // hit it, we'll call this handler to let it delete all the expired sessions.
    if ($this->configHitsLottery($config)) {
        $session->getHandler()->gc($this->getSessionLifetimeInSeconds());
    }
}

/**
 * Determine if the configuration odds hit the lottery.
 *
 * @param  array  $config
 * @return bool
 */
protected function configHitsLottery(array $config)
{
    return random_int(1, $config['lottery'][1]) <= $config['lottery'][0];
}
```

The default value is in config/session.php is [2, 100].

So configHitsLottery() would calculate a [random integer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) between 1 and 100 and will compare it to 2, like this:

```
return random_int(1, 100) <= 2;
```